# Set appropriate logging level using log4j in spock groovy framework

Tags: groovy, log4j, spock

I am new to both spock framework and groovy.
In my test project I am trying to set the log4j configuration to 'INFO' but when I run spock 'Specification' classes individually or through 'gradle test' it seem to log all the messages.

here is my 'log4jconfig.groovy' file

```
log4j {

appender.stdout = "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"
appender."stdout.layout"="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
appender.scrlog = "org.apache.log4j.FileAppender"
appender."scrlog.layout"="org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout"
appender."scrlog.file"="script.log"

rootLogger="info,scrlog,stdout"
}
```

and my 'SpockConfig.groovy'

```
import org.apache.log4j.*
import groovy.util.logging.*

def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('src/test/resources /log4jconfig.groovy').toURL())
PropertyConfigurator.configure(config.toProperties())
Logger log = Logger.getInstance(getClass())

log.level = Level.INFO
```

and my 'service' class seem to log even debug messages

```
@Log4j 
class PasswordResetService extends BaseService {
   def updateCustomerPassword(String oldpassword, String newpassword, String accessToken){
       log.debug("new password "+ newpassword)
   }
}
```

Am I missing anything.

Thanks.

Comment: I still could not make log4j working for my groovy project. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your service:

```
log.info "new password "+ newpassword //writes an info-level message 
log.warn "new password "+ newpassword //writes a warning-level message
log.error "new password "+ newpassword //guess what
log.debug "new password "+ newpassword //the one that you were executing
```

Recheck the spock config, I believe some stuff may be removed from there.